# $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{-x} \cos(x)}{\sin{\frac{1}{x}}}$

Tags: limits

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{-x} \cos(x)}{\sin{\frac{1}{x}}}
$$

I can make the substitution $\frac{1}{x} = n$ for $\lim_{n \to 0}$ and thus being able to write 
$$
\lim_{n \to 0} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{n}} \cos(\frac{1}{n})}{\sin{n}}
$$

and then substituting $\sin{n}$ with the asymptotic

$$
\lim_{n \to 0} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{n}} \cos(\frac{1}{n})}{n}
$$

but then I get stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: try to use L'Hôpital rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it this way: $sin(\frac{1}{x})$ ~ $\frac{1}{x}$ when $x \rightarrow +\infty $

Hence, if you call your expression f(x), you get:

$f(x)$ ~  $\frac{cos(x)}{\frac{e^x}{x}} $,when $x \rightarrow +\infty  $

But $\frac{e^x}{x} \rightarrow +\infty$ when $x \rightarrow +\infty$ and cos is bounded, so you get:

$f(x) \rightarrow 0$ when $x \rightarrow +\infty$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$|\cos x|\le 1$$
and

$$\frac{1}{\sin\left(\frac1x\right)}\sim_\infty x$$

so

$$\left| \frac{e^{-x} \cos(x)}{\sin{\frac{1}{x}}}\right|\le \frac{e^{-x}}{|\sin\frac1x|}\sim_\infty xe^{-x}\xrightarrow{x\to\infty}0$$